# Can auditd logs be modified? (Security, shell monitoring)

Tags: linux, security, shell, auditd

I recently set up auditd and enabled TTY logging so I could give someone non-root shell access and monitor what they're doing. (For what it's worth I gave them jailshell access, a cPanel feature that restricts their access to only their user directory.)

I had it set up correctly, and to test it I was running `aureport --tty -i` to see all user activity and `ausearch -ul _username_ | aureport --tty -i` to filter the activity of the new account (hereby named `_username_`, a pseudonym). On the `_username_` account, I just ran some simple commands like `cd` and `ls`. I also compared this with `cat /home/_username_/.bash_history`. I was logging in every day to check for updates, and I'm certain that I kept seeing the same record of activity from `_username_`, the basic aforementioned commands. I know I saw this activity because I remember being confused that I didn't see it logged in `aureport` until after I logged out. I had to Google to find out that this was a limitation of non-root TTY logging. So it was definitely in the `aureport` a few days ago.

So today, I check again, and this time there is new activity for `_username_`. Some pretty innocuous-looking commands. Frankly, I was expecting the person with the account to have more activity. What is very disconcerting to me, however, is that there is no previous record of activity from `_username_`. My original test commands are no longer being reported by `aureport`.

Is it possible they got up to no good, somehow got root access, and erased their history from `auditd`, accidentally erasing the history of my test commands in the process? Are there any other explanations?

Comment: Your auditd might be configured to limit the size of your logs and older events may have been deleted automatically by the system ; check your auditd.conf and `man 5 auditd.conf` for options and settings

Comment: That seems to be it. Combination of `max_log_file` and `num_logs` caused the history of my test commands to be rotated out. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my earlier comment:

Rather than abuse I expect that your log files reached either a maximum size or the events happend more than X time ago and the oldest entries were simply deleted by the system.

Most systems are configured with defaults that won't keep logs indefinitely and packagers typically include either a log rotate drop-in script (in `/etc/logrotate.d`) or if the service supports such a thing, age and/or size limits for logs in the daemon itself.

Auditd is of the second variety.

Check your `auditd.conf` for your current settings and `man 5 auditd.conf` for all supported options and defaults; such as the settings for `max_log_file` and `num_logs` that you found.

To answer the title of your question:

> Can auditd logs be modified?

Yes: if you give people administrator level access they usually can modify your whole system. That is why it is best practice to duplicate log events to a secure remote logging server.